# Horizontal alignment issues and differences using \\ and \newline in the text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, line-spacing

This minimal example shows the behaviour I am wondering about:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter 
\pagestyle{plain} 
\newgeometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\textsc{\Huge Super duper words\newline 
for whatever title it will\newline 
have in the end}

\vspace{2cm}

\textsc{\Huge Super duper words\\
for whatever title it will\\
have in the end}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

which compiles to

[image: PDF Screenshot]

Thus, using `\\` does not affect horizontal alignment but results in "improper" line spacing while `\newline` is messing up alignment.

I know that

```
\textsc{\Huge Super duper words}

\textsc{\Huge for whatever title it will}

\textsc{\Huge have in the end}
```

does the right thing but the actual command is

```
\textsc{\Huge \phdtitle}
```

which I cannot split up.

Comment: With font size switches you need to end the paragraph (using `\par`, for example) to have the correct baselineskip applied. However, \par cannot be used inside `\textsc`, but you can use `\scshape` instead: `{\scshape\Huge 
Super duper words\\
for whatever title it will\\
have in the end\par}` or `{\scshape\Huge\phdtitle\par}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Why is there a font size switch? Shouldn't the whole string be the same size?

Comment: `\Huge` *is* a font size switch.

Comment: I thought of a font size switch "within" the text.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: When reading "font size switch" I thought of the different line-spacings to arise from messed up fontsize of the lines. (First line having its post-line-space from a different "font-size" than second and third lines.) The `\scshape` tip works quite well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Pixelchemist all your lines were set with `\normalsize`  line spacing with `\Huge` text (which does not fit) that is why you shoud always include the end of paragraph in a size change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've never used `\newline` in one of my documents. I've used lots of `\\` (but never for ending paragraphs, of course) and several `\linebreak`.

What's `\newline` for? I don't really know and I don't care; what I know is that it should never be used in the text of a `center`, `flushleft` or `flusright` environment or under the scope of `\centering`, `\raggedright` or `\raggedleft`.

For setting font attributes in a `center` environment, such as for the title of a dissertation, use the “declarative” forms:

```
\begin{center}
\Huge\scshape
Super duper words\\
for whatever title it will\\
have in the end
\end{center}
```

Note `\\` and not `\newline`. If the title is in a macro, don't worry:

```
\begin{center}
\Huge\scshape\phdtitle
\end{center}
```

will do the right thing.

What happens in your first case? The `\textsc` command places its argument in a group, so the paragraph is prepared using `\Huge` but ends when this size declaration has lost its effect: the three line paragraph has wrong leading. Note that `\newline` never issues an end of paragraph.

The second case has three paragraphs, because `\\` effectively ends one. So the first two are typeset (centered) under the `\Huge` specific leading, but the last one has the wrong leading for the same reason as before.